# Adding JAVA_HOME (JDK) in .bashrc

Tags: java, environment-variables, bashrc

I just installed Ubuntu and am Java 7u55 (JDK) and am trying to configure JAVA_HOME as an environment variable.

In `~/.bashrc` I added:

```
# Exports
JAVA_HOME=/home/myuser/sandbox/java/7u55/jdk1.7.0_55
export PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME
```

Yet when I close the terminal and open a new shell and type `which java` or `java -version` Ubuntu doesn't seem to know what I'm talking about (says program `java` can be found in one of several packages and prompts me to use `sudo apt-get` to install one of them).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you have a typo in export line. It should be

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

No space, add a $ character before JAVA_HOME, add `/bin`

However fixing above line may not fix your problem in installing java. The easiest way to install java is by using webup8 ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

After the last command, the script will automatically download the jdk from Oracle website and install it for you. You can read the tutorial [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

Answer (score 4):

You have set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`, but this is only a value used by applications that want to know where the JRE or JDK are.

The `PATH` is what your shell is looking in when you try to run executables.  So when you type `java -version`, it is looking in the JDK folder.  Note that `java` is actually inside `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.   That's why it can't find it.

That's the explanation.

The fix is to either add it to the `$PATH` properly:

```
export PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin
```

or to run `update-alternatives` and [add the JDK path](http://www.code-complete.com/code/index.php?/archives/46-using-update-alternatives-to-add-additional-java-versions-to-etcalternatives.html) to the system's java alternatives.

For example

```
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/home/myuser/sandbox/java/7u55/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java" 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop not finding jdk thats why this error coming. By default jre used and it don't have javac file which is required to compile sqoop jobs.

Solution:

if jdk installed on the system then configure the same in hadoop-env.sh file
like:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_151/
```

And in .bash_profile file.

like:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin
```

then run source . .bash_profile

thats it now test sqoop job will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

Comment: It's a good practice to briefly explain what's happening, Shedrack.