# Setting up JAVA_HOME in .bashrc file to run wso2.sh file

Tags: command-line, java, bashrc

I'm trying to set up [wso2](http://wso2.com/) following this [tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Installing+on+Linux+or+OS+X), and I am having some issues setting the JAVA_HOME variable.

I found this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451261/adding-java-home-jdk-in-bashrc) setting the path to the `jdk`, but I get the following output when I open a new terminal window:

```
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
 * /bin/lesspipe
 * /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

This is my currrent path vaiable:

```
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/home/username/java/jdk1.8
```

-----------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------

```
export JAVA_HOME="home/username/java/jdk1.8"
export PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME
```

Now the bash file seems to working fine, but i still get an error when i try to run the wso2server.sh file, with the following output:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
 CARBON cannot execute /username/java/jdk1.8/bin/java
```

--------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------------

running this command to find my path:

```
readlink -f (which java)
```

gives:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

could this be the right path? The path provided in the earlier update does not lead to the jdk

Comment: I linked that question in my post and followed the instructions, this returns the same output(as shown above) when i open a new terminal window

Comment: `export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/home/username/java/jdk1.8` is not correct. This will put java_home in from of /home/.../ You are missing a `:` . All the examples in the link you post have a :. Why didn't you? And secondly "username" in a path?

Comment: Can you please be more secure? "/usernamr/`" what is that supposed to be? "/username"?  And if you typed actually "/username" as the error notice suggests... you need to put your username there. Not "username".